# Concatenating special characters in SASS/SCSS

Tags: css, sass, scss-lint

I have created a mixin in SASS and the codes as below.

```
@mixin skew($axis, $a) {
  transform: skew+$axis+($a);
  -o-transform: skew+$axis+($a);
  -moz-transform: skew+$axis+($a);
  -webkit-transform: skew+$axis+($a);
}
```

But the output it shows as

```
transform:skewY-4deg;
-o-transform:skewY-4deg;
-moz-transform:skewY-4deg;
-webkit-transform:skewY-4deg
```

I want to add parentheses around `-4deg` i.e. `transform: skewY(-4deg)`

Can someone correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@mixin skew($axis, $a) {
  transform: skew+$axis+"("+$a+")";
  -o-transform: skew+$axis+"("+$a+")";
  -moz-transform: skew+$axis+"("+$a+")";
  -webkit-transform: skew+$axis+"("+$a+")";
}
```

Comment: thanks Warch for the answer. Please correct the ans i.e. remove "+" plus sign between $axis and # `skew+$axis#{'('}$a#{')'};`

Comment: the other answer added spaces to the result... my solution now works better

Comment: Yes @Warch the corrected ans is working perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: My rank is too low dear. So I can't up vote. I have accepted this answer as a correct answer.